# BigQuery SQL Exclusion NOT IN empty results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm having problems with this not returning any values. There are accounts in the database that match this criteria. Somewhat confused why they aren't being returned.
Any suggestions?

```
select accountid from `table1` 
where not in (select accountid from `table1` where action != "Action8")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `not in`.  Semantically, it is counter-intuitive.  If *any* values in the subquery are `NULL`, then no rows are returned.

Use `not exists` instead;

```
select t1.accountid
from `table1` t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.accountid  = t1.accountid and
                        tt1.action <> 'Action8'
                 );
```

Or use `group by` and `having`:

```
select t1.accountid
from table1 t1
group by t1.accountid
having sum(case when action = 'Action8' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks I've been struggling with doing this without long winded joins for forever.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're referencing the field you don't want to be present in the subquery result:

```
select accountid from `table1` 
where accountid not in (select accountid from `table1` where action != "Action8")
```